# Subclassed UICollectionViewCell is not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Why aren't my subclassed cells displaying?

I've tried calling awake From **Nib** and `initWithCoder` and `initWithFrame` but none of the attributes are displaying

```
 @interface PhotoCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImageView;
 @end
```

And in my .m file

```
 @implementation PhotoCollectionViewCell
 -(void)awakeFromNib {
  self.photoImageView.frame = self.bounds;
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
 }

 -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  if (self) {
    self.photoImageView.frame = self.bounds;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
  }
  return self;
 }
```

My cell's class in interfacebuilder is set to `PhotoCollectionViewCell` and the reuse identifer is properly set in interfacebuilder

```
 @interface HomeViewController () {
   NSMutableArray *photosArray;
 }
 @end
```

And `homeview.m` file

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
   [self.collectionView registerClass:[PhotoCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell"];
   photosArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   UIImage *placeholder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
  [photosArray addObject:placeholder];
 }

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return photosArray.count;
 }

 - (PhotoCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   PhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.photoImageView.image = [photosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
 }
```

[image: des]

[image: dfa]

[image: df]

Comment: You don't need to register the class or the nib. That's what you're doing already in the storyboard. By registering the class you are overriding the storyboard and you will get your cell but with none of the outlets connected. Remove the line `registerClass...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register the class or the nib. That's what you're doing already in the storyboard. By registering the class you are overriding the storyboard and you will get your cell but with none of the outlets connected.

Remove the line...

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[PhotoCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell"];
```

You don't need it because you're doing it in the Storyboard.

Comment: beautiful! thank you. I actually did read the apple documentation on it and that wasn't annotated in there at all. I would have spent hours without even trying that. And unfortunately all the tutorials i looked at had that in their tutorial even if they were using storyboard. downfall of trusting tutorials i guess. thanks

Answer (score -1):

In homeview.m you should register the NIB not the class.

```
UINib *cellnib = [UINib nibWithNibName:PhotoCollectionViewCell bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellnib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"photoCell"];
```

Comment: i'm not using a nib and it's not a tableView